# On Urban airship push notifican arise than app crash in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.ios, urbanairship.com

I am creating Push notification with deep links and I test deep link but it works fine for me and redirect me to a particular page and when I try to handle notification at that time app is terminated and app is in crash mode and at that time I try to find best solution but I can't find any If there is anyone who can help than I thankful to His/Her.

My Code for handle notification is listed below:

```
public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, 
         Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
       {
     try
       {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

        NSDictionary aps = userInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;
        var notificationTitle = (aps[new NSString("title")] as NSString).ToString();
        var notificationMessage = (aps[new NSString("job_id")] as NSString).ToString();
        var NotificationId = (aps[new NSString("notification_id")] as NSString).ToString();

        if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationState.Equals(UIApplicationState.Active))
        {
            //App is in foreground. Act on it.
        }
        else
        {                   
            App.Current.MainPage = new AppliedJobDetails(null, notificationMessage, NotificationId);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //LogInfo.ReportErrorInfo(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, "AppDelegate-DidReceiveRemoteNotification");

    }
 }
```

If there is anyone who get a best solution please help me and my try to approach in iOS device.

Comment: Add the Exception/Stacktrace to your question

Comment: There is no exception arise only when I tap on notification at that time It shows me a `The app is terminated`

Comment: In the code you posted, you are suppressing exceptions on that section of code via an empty catch block, so remove that the try/catch. If you still do not receive an exception.... then pull the crash report from the iOS log and symbolized it.

Comment: `An error occured on client IDB480760 while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/4.8.0.760/stop-app` it shows me this error can you please suggest me.

Comment: That does not help *much*, would need the Exception/Stacktrace or the symbolized crash report.... but as a guess, I would assume that is a Firebase error, possibly an SSL issue, you really need to look at the device log when this error appears.

Comment: I don't think that error is occurred from urban airship server because I received notification as per google it say to me that you are not manage the notification in that manner app is terminated

Comment: @DeepSoni When you didn't debug it, will it force quit when you tap this notification?

Comment: Yes it force stop the application and project that's why I am not able to debug that.